# what is apple iOS develop certificate and APNs Development iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, code-signing

In Apple development certificate page there are 2 types of certificate:

1. iOS development
2. APNs Development iOS

What is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

iOS development : this type of signing certificate called a development certificate to identify yourself,

APNs Development iOS:Establish connectivity between your notification server and the Apple Push Notification service sandbox environment.

Answer (score 7):

**iOS development certificate** is that provide you development authority (code signing) that provide your application to testing environment for specific devices.

while
 **APNS certificate** allow the "Apple Push notification service " using this certificate. you can able to use  "Apple Push notification service " for more detail of APNS refer this  link http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 this may help to understand about APNs.

Answer (score 0):

**iOS development certificate** is used for testing and deburing purpose.
 **APNS certificate** This is used for the push notification service. APNS communicate remote server to apple server for push notifications.